# Doctrine ORM nullable option not working with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**The problem:**
I'm trying to update a colum to drop the `NOT NULL` using ORM properties.

**The entity:**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EnvelopeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EnvelopeRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="envelopes")
 * @UniqueEntity("public_id")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Envelope {

     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\Uuid
     */
    private string $publicId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, options:{"default": null})
     */
    private string $fieldAltered = false;
}
```

When i run `doctrine:migrations:diff`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20210222180126 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public');
    }
}
```

The migration does not recognize that the `$fieldAltered` now is to be set to null.

**Considerations:**

- I know the `diff` compare the entity with the database.
- I've already (desperated) changeed the migration to set the `DEFAULT NULL`, so tecnicaly the `@Column(nullable=true)` should match with the default null on database and does not generate any sql on migartion

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be creating some kind of conflict, if the column is nullable then it should not have any default value, also you should not be manually setting the php default value to `false`. It looks like you should also change the type-hint to be the nullable one `?string`
Try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private ?string $fieldAltered;
```

[PHP 7.4 Typed class properties explained](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74)